# Web dedicated ip in shared hosting

Tags: php, web-hosting

I have a website but its dedicated IP it is showing in search engine
is there away to fix it so that it doesn't show the dedicated IP in search engine like this `(https//ip/index.htm)`. am on shared hosting

Comment: The IP got there somehow, so there are links somewhere on the Internet or in your pages that use the IP instead of the domain/host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid having duplicate content on different addresses in the first place.

Pick one hostname to be canonical (e.g. `www.example.com`) and configure your server to redirect any request to a different hostname (which doesn't have an explicit virtual host) to that. That will catch raw IP requests and `example.com`.

You can also add:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="the full, prefered url of the page">
```

---

Note that it will take some time before search engines reindex the URL and spot the redirect.

Comment: thanks i think this works because i have made search and most recommending this , let me try it

Comment: how long can it take to reindex the url on search engines

Comment: I haven't a clue.

Comment: @Steve the search engines vary the frequency with which they visit sites according to a number of parameters - there's no clear answer. An active site will be re-indexed more frequently than a quiet one. Typical re-index times can be days or weeks (or months if your site has had no updates for a long time). Fix your problems, and wait. Google have a search console that allows you to delete dead links and request a re-index, but don't expect anything too quick.

Answer (score -2):

You should contact your hosting support services. It sounds like there's a problem with the nameserver or with your domain setup.

Comment: If the problem was with the name server then that would prevent the domain name resolving to the IP address. It would have no effect on the accessibility of the website via the IP address without a human-friendly hostname.